# docker on windows 10 can't mount volumes when VPN enabled

Tags: docker, networking, windows-10, vpn

I'm seeing problems mounting local volumes when running docker on Windows 10.  The problems only appear when I have my company VPN enabled.

```
C:\Users\matt> docker run --rm -v d:/tmp:/data alpine ls /data
my_local_test_file.txt
```

When connected to VPN, I get this:

```
C:\Users\matt> docker run --rm -v d:/tmp:/data alpine ls /data
C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\Resources\bin\docker.exe: Error response from daemon: error while creating mount source path '/host_mnt/d/tmp': mkdir /host_mnt/d: file exists.
```

Docker version is 17.12.0-ce-win47

I believe the problem is that docker uses the network when mounting local volumes, and the VPN routes ALL network traffic via the VPN gateway, so docker can't see the local drive.

Is there a workaround for this?

I'm aware I could run docker within a linux VM, or use docker toolbox.  Neither of those are particularly good.

Is there another possible workaround?

Answer (score 3):

> the VPN routes ALL network traffic via the VPN gateway

You're probably right, in which case all traffic routed from Docker client to Docker daemon will also be through the VPN. When you use Docker CLI on Windows, it will connect to the Docker daemon which is accessible through the network. Using a VPN may disrupt this mechanism.

I think what's happening is:

- When VPN is disabled, you use the Docker daemon on your machine and everything works
- When VPN is enabled, another Docker daemon is used either because your VPN redirect traffic addressed to your Docker host (`127.0.0.1` by default or set via [`-H` flag or `DOCKER_HOST` env variable](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/cli/)). This means that somehow this IP or host exists on your VPN network and there is a Docker daemon listening on it (which is kind of odd admittedly, it may be risky to use that daemon)

If that's really happening, you'll certainly see different output from `docker ps -a`, `docker images`, etc. because you are connecting to different daemons. (the daemon accessible through your VPN is actually being owned by someone else, you'd better not use it!)

What you can do:

**Do not route 127.0.0.1 (or whatever is configured as Docker host) through your VPN**

Action to take will depend on the VPN software you are using, or you can add route directly on your windows machine ([here is a good article](https://www.cactusvpn.com/tutorials/how-to-bypass-vpn-for-specific-websites-and-ips-on-windows/) on the subject)

**Find out your IP when VPN is enabled and configure Daemon to listen to this IP**

- When your VPN is enabled, run `ipconfig /all` and find the interface used by your VPN and it's IP address, for example `10.142.0.12` (you can compare output before/after enabling VPN to identify which one it is)
- Configure your Docker daemon to listen this IP address and restart it. Either [use the UI](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-windows/#daemon), or on Windows config file is located at `%programdata%\docker\config\daemon.json` by default, you need to specify `"hosts": ["10.142.0.12", "127.0.0.1"]` for example ([see docs for details](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/dockerd/#daemon-configuration-file))
- Configure Docker host to `10.142.0.12` when VPN is enabled, either by setting environment variable `DOCKER_HOST=10.142.0.12` or with client `docker -H 10.142.0.12  <cmd>`

*/!\ Security note: this may present a security issue as anyone knowing your IP on the VPN network will be able to use the Daemon on your machine*

---

Hope this helps. I am not a Windows expert so I was not able to give details on Windows-related issues, but feel free to ask details if needed.